# Google Contacts script slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

My goal is really simple, which is to add contacts to Google Contacts App  from data range and label them as "Coworkers' and "My Contacts" so i can use them on my phone. The below is the working codes I just came up with.

```
function myFunction() {

  //deletecontacts();
  var gn=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Leader Directory (Read only)');
  var systemcon=ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts');
  var systemmy=ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: Coworkers');
  var valuerng=gn.getRange("A2:H138").getValues();

  for (var i=0;i<=gn.getLastRow()-2;i++){
    var newcontact=ContactsApp.createContact(valuerng[i][0],'' , valuerng[i][1]);
    newcontact.addPhone('MOBILE_PHONE',valuerng[i][2]);
    newcontact.addAddress('Chapel', valuerng[i][6]);
    newcontact.addAddress('Mailing', valuerng[i][4]);
    newcontact.addCompany(valuerng[i][7],'');
    systemmy.addContact(newcontact);
    systemcon.addContact(newcontact)
          }

      }
```

Can anyone modify them so they'd run faster? If I just upload the entire csv to Contacts App, it'd only take 3 seconds but my codes take something like 3 minutes. Another question is why the codes to add newly created contacts can only run at the end or more often than not,

```
 systemmy.addContact(newcontact);
    systemcon.addContact(newcontact)
```

would return null at random contacts and quit the function if they were executed right after a new contact is created?

Comment: Hello @KuanChunYeh, which runtime are you using for your script: **Rhino** or **V8**? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 Thanks for the follow up. it's V8 runtime that I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your script is slow is because each instruction in your `for` loop is actually making an `update` request, resulting in four `update` requests and one `post` request (when creating the contact).

Unfortunately, there is no way to reduce this to just one `update` request since all the methods you have used - `addPhone()`,`addAddress()`,`addCompany()` - expect a `Contact` but return a different type, therefore, making it impossible calling them one after the other.

Since this is not a viable option for you, you might want to take a look at the `People API`.

You can send this `POST` request:

```
POST https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact
```

With the following request body:

```
{
  "names": [],
  "emailAddresses": [],
  "phoneNumbers": [],
  "addresses": [],
  "organizations": []
}
```

**Reference**

- [Contacts Service Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts#contact);
- [People API Create Contact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact);
- [People API REST Resource: people](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person).